# Create tabs on popups with CefSharp.WpfExample

Tags: wpf, tabs, popup, cefsharp

While using the downloaded project from: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master and using CefSharp.WpfExample, I would like to send popups to new tabs instead of new windows.

I read that this is handled by

```
    bool lifespanhandler.onbeforepopup
```

in

```
     public class lifespanhandler : ilifespanhandler
```

But, there seems to be no handlers in the actual example, when trying to copy the

```
    LifeSpanHandler.cs
```

From another project in the same folder in the CefSharp.WpfExample handlers (for example using the one in CefSharp handlers folder), It seems to never be reached (while using breakpoints).

The goal would simply be to load all popups and new windows in tabs instead, as the example is already using a TabControl, I would build my own project around around it.

May you help me figuring this one out please?

All the help is greatly welcome and appreciated!

UPDATE #01

I was able to find this

```
// This LifeSpanHandler implementaion demos hosting a popup in a ChromiumWebBrowser
// instance, it's still considered Experimental. The ChromiumWebBrowser
// is shown in a new Window. This could just as easily be a Tab/ContentControl/etc

browser.LifeSpanHandler = CefSharp.Wpf.Experimental.LifeSpanHandler
    .Create()
    .OnPopupCreated((ctrl, targetUrl, targetFrameName, windowInfo) =>
    {
        var windowX = (windowInfo.X == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.X;
        var windowY = (windowInfo.Y == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Y;
        var windowWidth = (windowInfo.Width == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Width;
        var windowHeight = (windowInfo.Height == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Height;

        var popup = new System.Windows.Window
        {
            Left = windowX,
            Top = windowY,
            Width = windowWidth,
            Height = windowHeight,
            Content = ctrl,
            Owner = Window.GetWindow(browser),
            Title = targetFrameName
        };

        popup.Closed += (o, e) =>
        {
            var w = o as System.Windows.Window;
            if (w != null && w.Content is IWebBrowser)
            {
                (w.Content as IWebBrowser)?.Dispose();
                w.Content = null;
            }
        };
    })
```

in

```
BrowserTabView.xaml.cs
```

Any ideas how this could be changed to use the actual TabControl of the following project to use tabs instead please?

```
CefSharp.WpfExample
```

UPDATE #02

From what I understand, I would need to access the

```
BrowserTabs = new ObservableCollection<BrowserTabViewModel>();
```

in

```
MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

from

```
browser.LifeSpanHandler = CefSharp.Wpf.Experimental.LifeSpanHandler
    .Create()
    .OnPopupCreated((ctrl, targetUrl, targetFrameName, windowInfo) =>
    {
        var windowX = (windowInfo.X == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.X;
        var windowY = (windowInfo.Y == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Y;
        var windowWidth = (windowInfo.Width == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Width;
        var windowHeight = (windowInfo.Height == int.MinValue) ? double.NaN : windowInfo.Height;

        var popup = new System.Windows.Window
        {
            Left = windowX,
            Top = windowY,
            Width = windowWidth,
            Height = windowHeight,
            Content = ctrl,
            Owner = Window.GetWindow(browser),
            Title = targetFrameName
        };

        popup.Closed += (o, e) =>
        {
            var w = o as System.Windows.Window;
            if (w != null && w.Content is IWebBrowser)
            {
                (w.Content as IWebBrowser)?.Dispose();
                w.Content = null;
            }
        };
    })
```

in

```
BrowserTabView.xaml
```

Which is currently the step I am stuck on, after, I suppose the tab could be added with something like:

```
BrowserTabs.Add(new BrowserTabViewModel(url) { ShowSidebar = showSideBar, LegacyBindingEnabled = legacyBindingEnabled });
```

May anyone help me with this please? A code example would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE #03

Some progression!

I was change some code to create a tab

```
browser.LifeSpanHandler = CefSharp.Wpf.Experimental.LifeSpanHandler
    .Create()
    .OnPopupCreated((ctrl, targetUrl, targetFrameName, windowInfo) =>
    {
        ctrl.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            MainWindow my = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
            my.BrowserTabs.Add(new BrowserTabViewModel(targetUrl) { }); //ShowSidebar = showSideBar, LegacyBindingEnabled = legacyBindingEnabled });
        }));
    })
```

But this works only once, unless the newly created tab is closed, if I try to create a new one, I get the following error

```
System.ArgumentException
HResult=0x80070057
Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at CefSharp.Wpf.Experimental.LifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser) in CENSORED\CefSharp-master\CefSharp.Wpf\Experimental\LifespanHandler.cs:line 231
at CefSharp.Handler.LifeSpanHandler.CefSharp.ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser) in CENSORED\CefSharp-master\CefSharp\Handler\LifeSpanHandler.cs:line 102
at CefSharp.Internals.ClientAdapter.OnAfterCreated(ClientAdapter* , scoped_refptr<CefBrowser>* browser) in CENSORED\CefSharp-master\CefSharp.Core.Runtime\Internals\ClientAdapter.cpp:line 244
```

on

```
protected override void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
{
    // For DevTools/Native Popup windows pendingChromiumWebBrowser should be null
    if (browser.IsPopup && pendingChromiumWebBrowser != null)
    {
        chromiumWebBrowserMap.Add(browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle(), pendingChromiumWebBrowser);
```

Any ideas how I can change this behavior to allow for several tab creation please?

Again, all the help is appreciated, almost there!

Comment: The example would need a major restructure to support hosting popups as tabs, so there's no working example currently. In `OnPopupCreated` you should add the `ctrl` param to your tab. Don't create a new tab with the targetUrl. You will need to handle closing of tabs, you've dropped part of the example https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/120/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Views/BrowserTabView.xaml.cs#L126